# Sending data from .js to JSON using POST

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have some inputs that are being filled in by the user, to simplify things it will just be name/surname. My idea is to get this data to be able to edit a JSON file I have locally to add this information. I don't know if this is possible. This is the code I have for my .js :

```
function submitContacto(e) {
   
   var name= $("#name").val();
   var surname= $("#surname").val();
   
  
   var toSend={
       [name] : name,
       [surname] : surname,
       
       
   };
   
   var jsonString = JSON.stringify(toSend);
   console.log(jsonString);
   const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open("POST", "./contactJSON");
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
   xhr.send(jsonString);
}
```

As of now, the console logs the jsonString that was created correctly, but I then there is an error that says "POST http://127.0.0.1:5500/contactJSON 405 (Method Not Allowed)". I am not sure if this error is because I am doing something wrong, or if it is impossible to send the data directly from a JavaScript file to edit a JSON file.

Comment: it means contactJSON api is using method other than "POST" method. Check if the server is using "GET", "PUT" or something else

Comment: why you dont use [jQuery Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)?

Answer (score 0):

Method now allowed means that the url is good but the method is not.

So here no `POST` is allowed.
You can verify with `curl '' -X POST`

If your server is coded correctly, send this request in terminal:

`curl 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/contactJSON' -i`
and check the value of `Allow`.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 28 Nov 2020 11:18:28 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 2
Connection: keep-alive
Allow: GET
```

BTW, current browser implemts fetch API, take a look

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch